# Changing Spring configuration file name extension .properties to something else

Tags: spring, configuration-files, spring-java-config, spring-config

Is there a way to override Spring's default file extension for the properties file?  I know that you can change the name with the ***spring.config.name*** setting, and the location with the ***spring.config.location*** setting, but it still expects the file to have a filename extension of ***.properties***.  So far I have been unable to tell it to use a file like ***system.props*** as a properties file.

Comment: Hello, welcome to StackOverflow! Why do you want to change the extension in the first place?

Comment: I have a legacy system that uses an existing file for its properties, so I am pretty much stuck with having to use that file and it doesn't end in .properties